# How to avoid gap in autoplot() function and change color of the curve

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I'm trying to plot time series using the autoplot() function but I have two problems:

1-  there is a gap in the curve between the data and the predicted values.

2-I'm not able to change the color of the curve

[image: graph]

my code:

```
mod <- arima(drivers, order = c(3, 1,2), seasonal = list(order= c(0, 1, 1), 
period = 12))
SARIMA.pred <- forecast(mod, h = 12)
autoplot(SARIMA.pred, ts.colour ="darkblue", include=24)
```

Do you know what's wrong?
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957519/786542

Comment: Thank you very much!  the author doesn't use autoplot() but symply plot() with option showgap=F, I will not use autoplot it does not seems to be the best package