# Add legend entry for prediction line in R's forecast package

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecasting

I have a plot of a forecast object obtained through `fcast <- forecast(Arima(data$train, order=...))`:

```
fcast %>% autoplot(series='Forecast') +
  autolayer(fitted(fit), series='Fitted') + 
  autolayer(data$train, series = 'Train') +
  autolayer(data$test, series='Test') +
  xlab("Observation [days]") +
  ylab("Energy [Watts]") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Data series"), 
         fill=guide_legend(title="Prediction interval"))
```

That looks like this:
[image]

As you can see I added everything to the legend except the dark blue line that represents the predicted points.

How can I add the predicted points (the dark blue line) to the legend?

EDIT:
The solution, based on Rob Hyndman's answer:

```
clrs <- c("blueviolet", "blue", "darkgoldenrod4", "red")

autoplot(fcast) +
  autolayer(fcast$mean, series="Forecast") +
  autolayer(fitted(fit), series='Fitted') + 
  autolayer(data$train, series = 'Train') +
  autolayer(data$test, series='Test') +
  xlab("Observation [days]") +
  ylab("Energy [Watts]") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Data series"), 
         fill=guide_legend(title="Prediction interval")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=clrs)
```

[image]

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957203/overlapping-the-predicted-time-series-on-the-original-series-in-r/49957519#49957519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it again with an `autolayer`:

```
autoplot(fcast) +
  autolayer(fcast$mean, series="Forecast") +
  autolayer(fitted(fit), series='Fitted') + 
  autolayer(data$train, series = 'Train') +
  autolayer(data$test, series='Test') +
  xlab("Observation [days]") +
  ylab("Energy [Watts]") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Data series"), 
         fill=guide_legend(title="Prediction interval"))
```

Then you might need to play with the colours.

Comment: Upvoted, since this does indeed what I requested, but I'm not sure how I would go about matching the colors, not the prediction intervals have a differnt color than what is on the legend (the default blue). Any hints please?

Comment: Indeed, it worked on the default `colour` aesthetic, I edited my answer with the final code. But still, I wasn't able to change the two little squares in the legend by using `... + scale_color_manual(values=c("#FF0000", "#0000FF"), aesthetics = "fill")` due to "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale". Accepted the answer since it led to the solution, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I made the following but still I could not get the legends

```
 autoplot(arima_kw_Pat)+
      xlab("Day")+
      ylab("Under Treatment")+
      ggtitle("Patients Under Treatment in Kuwait ARIMA")+
      guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Data series"), 
              fill=guide_legend(title="Prediction interval"))+
      scale_color_manual(values=clrs)
```

instead I got the following error
Error in is_missing(values) : object 'clrs' not found

Comment: Is this an answer? Seems more like a question or a comment? check out [answer]

Comment: This should indeed be another question altogether, but as the error says, you're missing the `clrs` variable, see my code for its definition.