# How to add the legend shown in this cumulative moving average forecast graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate the legend on this cumulative moving average forecast graph

[image: cumulative moving average forecast graph] but the closest I can get is this.[image: Graph].

[This is the link to the data:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hlQ4YNmXJs3jyJHyyprBZARvufr-cWSVnACva1xTsiM/edit?usp=sharing)

I can't figure out the ggplot2 (I'm assuming ggplot2 as the lecturer hasn't supplied the code, probably intentionally) arguments for the legend.

Here's what I've got so far.

```r
ggplot2::autoplot(beard.ts, series = "Beards (on men)") +
    ggplot2::ggtitle("Percentage of men with a full beard") +
    ggplot2::autolayer(beard.fitted) +
    ggplot2::autolayer(beard.fitted$mean, series = "Mean Estimate") +
    ggplot2::guides(guide_legend()) +
    ggplot2::xlab("Year") + 
    ggplot2::ylab("Percentage (%)")
```

EDIT: Additional info

I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997855/add-legend-entry-for-prediction-line-in-rs-forecast-package) that shows the result I'm looking for but, although my new code runs without error, the "Prediction interval" legend doesn't appear.

```r
beards <- read.csv("percent-of-men-with-full-beards.csv")
beard.ts <- ts(beards$Beards, start = 1866)
beard.fitted <- meanf(beard.ts, h = 6)

autoplot(beard.ts, series = "Beards (on men)") +
  autolayer(beard.fitted, PI = T) +
  autolayer(beard.fitted$mean, series = "Mean Estimate") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Percentage (%)") +
  ggtitle("Percentage of men with a full beard") +
  guides(
    fill = guide_legend(title = "Prediction interval"),
    colour = guide_legend(title = "Data series")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "red"))
```

At least I was able to make the colours change... [image: Updated graph].

Comment: Also, assuming ggplot2 as other code from this lecturer uses ggplot2.

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question, I am just curious, you are aware you can use "library(ggplot2)" instead of writing "ggplot2::" in front of every function? Also please provide some sample data, increases your chances of getting the answer.

Comment: Yes, I would normally load the library but this lecturer is writing it that way and I'm already on their bad side, so I'm following suit.

There is a link to the data in the post.