# Plot forecast and actual values

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I all. I need some help from statistics expert. I have made a simple arima forecast for few values in `as`. But I have taken a subset of values in `train_as`.

Now is there a way to plot both actual values and forecasted values here. Like the actual values in 2019 is 4,8,12,16 and the forecast is 9,10,11,12. Can we plot this?

```
as <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,2,4,6,8,4,8,12,16))
train_as <- as[c(1:8),]
a1 <- ts(train_as,start = c(2017,1),end = c(2017,8),frequency = 4)
fit_arima <-auto.arima(a1, trace= TRUE, ic ="aic")
print(summary(fit_arima))
checkresiduals(fit_arima)
fcst <- forecast(fit_arima,h=4)
autoplot(fcst,include = 8)
```

Comment: Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56180717/r-how-to-show-forecast-and-actual-data-in-a-single-plot?

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to do using the forecast package with the `autolayer()` function.

```r
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)

as <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6, 8, 4, 8, 12, 16))

# Convert to a time series
y <- ts(as$a, start = 2017, frequency = 4)

# Split in two
a1 <- subset(y, end = 8)
a2 <- subset(y, start = 9)

# Fit model
fit_arima <- auto.arima(a1, ic = "aic")

# Compute forecasts
fcst <- forecast(fit_arima, h = 4)

# Plot forecasts and test set
autoplot(fcst) + autolayer(a2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, first you create your test dataset:

```
test_as <- as[c(9:12),]
```

Now a `data.frame` to plot, you can see the `real` data, the `time`, and the predicted values (and their ICs) that should be with the same length of the time and real data, so I pasted a `NA`s vector with length equal to the difference between the real data and the predicted, and the predicted (same for the ICs). Note the time is generated by quarter with `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)
df <-
data.frame(real = as$a,
           pred = c(rep(NA,length(as$a)-length(data.frame(fcst)[,1])),data.frame(fcst)[,1]),
           time =  zoo::as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2019/12/1"), by = "quarter"), format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
           Lo80 =c(rep(NA,length(as$a)-length(data.frame(fcst)[,2])),data.frame(fcst)[,2]),
           Hi80 =c(rep(NA,length(as$a)-length(data.frame(fcst)[,3])),data.frame(fcst)[,3]),
           Lo95 =c(rep(NA,length(as$a)-length(data.frame(fcst)[,4])),data.frame(fcst)[,4]),
           Hi95 =c(rep(NA,length(as$a)-length(data.frame(fcst)[,5])),data.frame(fcst)[,5]))
```

Now you can plot it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(time, pred, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(time, real, group = 1), color = "red")+
  geom_ribbon(aes(time, ymin = Lo95, ymax = Hi95), fill = "red", alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(time, ymin = Lo80, ymax = Hi80), fill = "red", alpha = 0.25) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]